# how to access python variable inside a vue.js input fields

Tags: python, django, vue.js

Here I have written python code. So in this python code I have an variable "query_class" That i want to acces in below vue.js template inside the input fields. So how can we do that if anyone have an idea please let  me know

```
def PostAdUpdate(request, adv_id):
    if ((request.session.get('email') is None) or (request.session.get('email') == "")):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
    `query_class` = classifieds.objects.filter(email=request.session.get('email'), id=adv_id).first()
    query_tran = transaction_table.objects.filter(classifieds_id=adv_id).first()
    query_master = master_fields.objects.filter(classifieds_id=adv_id).first()
    return render(request, 'postAdUpdate.html', {'query_cart': query_class,
                                                 'query_tran': query_tran,
                                                 'query_master': query_master,
                                                 })
```

**template here inside of this input field I want to access the above python code variable that is "query_class"**

```
<div id="vue">
    <input v-model.lazy="category" placeholder="Search your category" name="category" 
    maxlength="200" id="id_post_type">
</div>
```

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    category:'',
  },
  methods: {},
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're already passing `query_class` to `render` (the first field named `query_cart`):

```py
return render(request, 'postAdUpdate.html', {'query_cart': query_class, 
                                             'query_tran': query_tran,
                                             'query_master': query_master,
                                             })
```

You could use the `query_cart` field as a [variable in your Django template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#variables) with interpolation. For example, initialize a Vue data property with it:

```html
<script>
new Vue({
  data: {
    query_class: '{{ query_cart }}',
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: This will cause a XSS attack if the query ever contains `</script>`, so don't use on untrusted data. Use the json_script filter for a more secure method